# How can I list all defined URL paths in FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Suppose I have a FastAPI project that contains 100+ API endpoints. **How can I list all APIs/paths?**

Answer (score 30):

To get all possible URL patterns, we need to get access to the ***defined URL routes*** which is an attribute of running app instance.

We can do that in at least two ways,

1. Using **`FastAPI`** app: This is handy when you have access to the FastAPi instance
2. Using **`Request`** instance: This is handy when you have access to the incoming requests, but not to the FastAPI instance.

---

#### Complete Example

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.get(path="/", name="API Foo")
def foo():
    return {"message": "this is API Foo"}


@app.post(path="/bar", name="API Bar")
def bar():
    return {"message": "this is API Bar"}


# Using FastAPI instance
@app.get("/url-list")
def get_all_urls():
    url_list = [{"path": route.path, "name": route.name} for route in app.routes]
    return url_list


# Using Request instance
@app.get("/url-list-from-request")
def get_all_urls_from_request(request: Request):
    url_list = [
        {"path": route.path, "name": route.name} for route in request.app.routes
    ]
    return url_list
```

Answer (score 10):

I tried to provide an edit the original answer but wouldn't let me.

Another use case: Suppose you are not in the main app file and don't have access to `app` in the namespace. In that case [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/requests/) documentation says that we also have access to the app instance from the request as `request.app`. For example if in the main file you only have the app instance and don't want to have any endpoints in the main file but all of them to be in separate routers.

main.py

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
# then let's import all the various routers we have
# please note that api is the name of our package
from api.routers import router_1, router_2, router_3, utils
app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(router_1)
app.include_router(router_2)
app.include_router(router_3)
app.include_router(utils)
```

I have my list_endpoints endpoint in the utils router. To be able to list all of the app routes, I would do the following:

utils.py

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/utils",
    tags=["utilities"]
)

@router.get('/list_endpoints/')
def list_endpoints(request: Request):
    url_list = [
        {'path': route.path, 'name': route.name}
        for route in request.app.routes
    ]
    return url_list
```

Note that rather than using `app.routes` I used `request.app.routes` and I have access to all of them. If you now access `/utils/list_endpoints` you will get all your routes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. btw I have updated the OP with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works great when you have just one app, but unfortunately, in our project we have a number of submounted ones which makes things a bit trickier in terms of traversal.

```py
app.mount("/admin", admin_app)
...
```

We also have a lot of routes and their unqualified names can be the same even within one app, let alone different ones. So I wanted to get an overview of all the routes and their matching functions.

That's how I approached it, hope it will be helpful to others. :)
Great framework, but really miss django-extensions which had that covered, too bad there's nothing of the sort in fastapi land. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Iterable

from app.main import app
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.routing import Mount


def gen_routes(app: FastAPI | Mount) -> Iterable[tuple[str, str]]:
    for route in app.routes:
        if isinstance(route, Mount):
            yield from (
                (f"{route.path}{path}", name) for path, name in gen_routes(route)
            )
        else:
            yield (
                route.path,
                "{}.{}".format(route.endpoint.__module__, route.endpoint.__qualname__),
            )


def list_routes(app: FastAPI) -> None:
    import tabulate

    routes = sorted(set(gen_routes(app)))  # also readable enough
    print(tabulate.tabulate(routes, headers=["path", "full name"]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_routes(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open `/docs` URI to get all URLs documented in OpenAPI (swagger) format.

Parsing URLs should be trivial.

On localhost: `http://localhost:8000/docs`

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @olegsv, this would be a solution:

```
import requests
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'  # local
response = requests.get(url+'openapi.json')
loaded_endpoints = list(response.json()['paths'].keys())
```