# How to overwrite/extend FastAPI - APIRouter route

Tags: python, fastapi

this question is related to [FastAPI with APIRouter plugin system not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72193090/fastapi-with-apirouter-plugin-system-not-working/72193552?noredirect=1#comment127560526_72193552) , just to give a little bit of context...

So... I'm trying to create a simple pluggable FastAPI application where plugins can add, or not, API endpoints. Now is working fine so every plugin adds its own API endpoints. But what if a plugin can extend other plugins, to add or modify its endpoints...

For that, I build a plugin graph to handle the plugin dependencies and now a plugin can import the router from its dependencies and add some new endpoints. But I can´t overwrite the existing endpoints with the new routes.

To make it simpler I wrote this piece of code to simulate this:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/")
def index():
    return "hello world!"


@router.get("/")
def new_index():
    return "hello world 2!"


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("server:app")
```

At this point, I would expect to have the `hello world 2!` response for the `/` route but instead of that I have the `hello world!`

**UPDATE**

I have also found another interesting thing in the generated api `/docs` that maybe can be a bug... (I update the routes functions name, to clarify). The code generates this doc... So I may think that it's Ok!. At least the documentation was built from the `new_index` function

[image]

But as I was mentioned before the response is from `index`

Comment: I suspect you should do a comparison while mounting and then unmount the routes that are conflicting or import only "the latest" here is where you can list all the routes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206332/how-can-i-list-all-defined-url-paths-in-fastapi

Comment: Probably worth having a look in the source code to understand how things behave under the hood. e.g. https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/bcabbf8b37db3fbc020560e94ad2f90e64d1510a/fastapi/routing.py#L504 we can see that each time you use the `get` decorator it appends to a list of routes. Presumably, when dispatching, FastAPI will then pick the first match from the list, instead of last added.  You could use that knowledge to make a new decorator with different behaviour, perhaps inserting at front of list instead of appending (or searching for existing match and replacing it)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to have a simple solution, hahaha. It seems that the solution lies in extending the APIRouter and modifying its behavior.